# How to add two different quizzes in only one javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web site with a quiz that works by accessing it from the main page button. The quiz is inside the Javascript file.
I want to make two quizzes that can be accessed from two buttons on the main page. How can I add this second quiz if the only thing that changes from the first quiz are the images, questions and answers.

Do I have to add another javascript file for the second quiz, can I add the information of the second quiz from the same javascript file?

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <title>ADIVINA LA BANDERA</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>FLAGS</h1>

<!-- Pantalla inicial -->
<div id="pantalla-inicial">
    <p>FLAGS</p>
    <button class="btn" onclick="startquiz1()">QUIZ 1</button>
</div>

<!-- Pantalla juego -->
<div class="pantalla-juego" id="pantalla-juego">
    <img src="img/ad.svg" alt="" id="imgBandera">
    <div class="opciones">
        <div class="opcion" id="op0" onclick="comprobarRespuesta(0)">
            <div class="letra" id="l0">A</div>
            <div class="nombre" id="n0">OPCION A</div>
        </div>
        <div class="opcion" id="op1" onclick="comprobarRespuesta(1)">
            <div class="letra" id="l1">B</div>
            <div class="nombre" id="n1">OPCION B</div>
        </div>
        <div class="opcion" id="op2" onclick="comprobarRespuesta(2)">
            <div class="letra" id="l2">C</div>
            <div class="nombre" id="n2">OPCION C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Pantalla final -->
<div id="pantalla-final">
    <h2>CORRECTAS: <span id="numCorrectas">3</span></h2>
    <h2>INCORRECTAS: <span id="numIncorrectas">2</span></h2>
    <button class="btn" onclick="volverAlInicio()">VOLVER AL INICIO</button>
</div>

<footer>Desarrollado por Código Web</footer>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT FILE COLDE

```
//cargo en un arreglo las imganes de las banderas. Este sera el orden que se mostrarán
let banderas = ["pa.svg", "bo.svg", "ad.svg", "gb.svg", "na.svg"];

//arreglo que guardara la opcion correcta
let correcta = [2,2,1,1,0];

//arreglo que guardara los paises a mostrar en cada jugada
let opciones = [];
//cargo en el arreglo opciones las opciones a mostrar en cada jugada
opciones.push(["SUDAFRICA", "SINGAPUR", "PANAMA"]);
opciones.push(["PERU", "ITALIA", "BOLIVIA"]);
opciones.push(["TUNEZ", "ANDORRA", "ANTIGUA Y BARBUDA"]);
opciones.push(["UCRANIA", "REINO UNIDO", "MADAGASCAR"]);
opciones.push(["NAMIBIA", "OMAN", "ETIOPIA"]);

//variable que guarda la posicion actual
let posActual = 0;
//variable que guarda la cantidad acertadas hasta el moemento
let cantidadAcertadas = 0;

function startquiz1(){
//reseteamos las variables
posActual = 0;
cantidadAcertadas = 0;
//activamos las pantallas necesarias
document.getElementById("pantalla-inicial").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("pantalla-juego").style.display = "block";
cargarBandera();

}

//funcion que carga la siguiente bandera y sus opciones
function cargarBandera(){
//controlo sis se acabaron las banderas
if(banderas.length <= posActual){
    terminarJuego();
}
else{//cargo las opciones
    //limpiamos las clases que se asignaron
    limpiarOpciones();

    document.getElementById("imgBandera").src = "img/" + banderas[posActual];
    document.getElementById("n0").innerHTML = opciones[posActual][0];
    document.getElementById("n1").innerHTML = opciones[posActual][1];
    document.getElementById("n2").innerHTML = opciones[posActual][2];
}
}

function limpiarOpciones(){
document.getElementById("n0").className = "nombre";
document.getElementById("n1").className = "nombre";
document.getElementById("n2").className = "nombre";

document.getElementById("l0").className = "letra";
document.getElementById("l1").className = "letra";
document.getElementById("l2").className = "letra";
}

function comprobarRespuesta(opElegida){
if(opElegida==correcta[posActual]){//acertó
    //agregamos las clases para colocar el color verde a la opcion elegida
    document.getElementById("n" + opElegida).className = "nombre nombreAcertada";
    document.getElementById("l" + opElegida).className = "letra letraAcertada";
    cantidadAcertadas++;
}else{//no acerto
    //agramos las clases para colocar en rojo la opcion elegida
    document.getElementById("n" + opElegida).className = "nombre nombreNoAcertada";
    document.getElementById("l" + opElegida).className = "letra letraNoAcertada";

    //opcion que era correcta
    document.getElementById("n" + correcta[posActual]).className = "nombre nombreAcertada";
    document.getElementById("l" + correcta[posActual]).className = "letra letraAcertada";
}
posActual++;
//Esperamos 1 segundo y pasamos mostrar la siguiente bandera y sus opciones
setTimeout(cargarBandera,1000);
}
function terminarJuego(){
//ocultamos las pantallas y mostramos la pantalla final
document.getElementById("pantalla-juego").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("pantalla-final").style.display = "block";
//agreamos los resultados
document.getElementById("numCorrectas").innerHTML = cantidadAcertadas;
document.getElementById("numIncorrectas").innerHTML = banderas.length - cantidadAcertadas;
}

function volverAlInicio(){
//ocultamos las pantallas y activamos la inicial
document.getElementById("pantalla-final").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("pantalla-inicial").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("pantalla-juego").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap each quiz into `<div class="quiz"></div>`.
- wrap your code in a function `createQuiz(container)`.
- Change your `document.getElementByID` to `container.querySelector('#...')`.
- Also I would recommend using CSS classes instead of IDs.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.quiz').forEach(createQuiz);
```

Comment: Hello Alexander, thank you for your answer but I don't know how to execute what you said (I'm a beginner).
Could be possible to send the modified code according to the answer you gave me, it would be the only way, for me,  to test if it works.). Thank you in advance